# why draftInlineStyleType in draft.js only can be default type?

Tags: draftjs

I defined editorStyleMap and use them

```
const editorStyleMap = { Choose: { color: '#4880f0' }, Black: { color: '#000000' } }
```

then I get the array of inlineStyleRanges

```
const messageBlocks=convertToRaw(editorState.getCurrentContent()).blocks[0].inlineStyleRanges;
```

i console every item of the array and the result is below,
item's style can be 'Choose' or 'Black'

> {offset: 3, length: 3, style: 'Choose'} {offset: 6, length: 5, style:
> 'Black'} {offset: 11, length: 3, style: 'Choose'} {offset: 14, length:
> 1, style: 'Black'}

but when i want to use if to judge the type of style

```
if(item.style==='Choose')
```

terminal reports an error

> 'This condition will always return 'false' since the types
> 'DraftInlineStyleType' and '"Choose"' have no overlap.'

it seems that styleType only can be default type like **'BOLD'** and *'ITALIC'*.

i don't know why??? if you could help me, i would be grateful:)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i use a strange way to solve the problem.
just use **String()** method to convert item.style to string type, and the string can be anything you define

```
if(String(item.style)==='Choose')
```

The terminal does not report an error